# Plotting a small Gaussian | Small values and dealing with machine precision

Tags: plotting, numerics

I've defined the following:

```
k := 1.38*10^-16
kev := 6.242*10^8
q := 4.8*10^-10
g := 1.66*10^-24
h := 6.63*10^-27
```

and

```
b = 
  ((2^(3/2)) (π^2)*1*6*(q^2)*(((1*g*12*g)/(1*g + 12*g))^(1/2)) )/h

T6 := 20
T := T6*10^6
e0 := ((b k T6 *10^6)/2)^(2/3)

Δ := 4/√3 (e0 k T6 *10^6)^(1/2)

Δkev = Δ*kev
e0kev = e0*kev
bkev = b*kev^(1/2)
```

Then, I want to plot these functions:

```
fexp1[x_] = E^(-bkev *(x*kev)^(-1/2))
fexp2[x_] = E^(-x/(k*T))
fexp3[x_] = fexp1[x]*fexp2[x]
```

and check that this Taylor expansion works:

```
fgauss[x_] = 
  Exp[(-3 (bkev^2/(4 k T*kev ))^(1/3))]Exp[(-((x*kev - e0kev)^2/(Δkev/2)^2))]
```

which should, e.g., as expected:

[image: Figure 10.1]

This plot came from ["Stellar Astrophysics notes" of Edward Brown](https://web.pa.msu.edu/people/ebrown/docs/stellar-notes.pdf) (also it is a known approximation).

I used this line of command to Plot:

```
Plot[{fexp1[x],fexp2[x],fexp3[x],fgauss[x]}, {x, 0, 50}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
    {{Blue, Dashed}, {Dashed, Green}, {Thick, Red}, {Thick, Black, Dashed}}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  GridLines -> {{{-1, Blue}, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Automatic}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> 
    {Style["Energía E", FontSize -> 25, Black], 
     Style["f(E)", FontSize -> 25, Black]}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[
      LineLegend[{"","","",""}, 
        Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[.9]], 
        LabelStyle -> {15}, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}], 
      {0.35, 0.75}]]
```

but it seems that Mathematica doesn't like huge negative exponentials. I know I can compute this using Python, but it's a surprise to think that Mathematica can't deal with the problem somehow. Could someone help me?

**EDIT**

Due to `JimB` contribution, using

```
Plot[{fexp1[x], fexp2[x], fexp3[x], fgauss[x]}, {x, 6.5 10^-9, 
  8*10^-7.7}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2*10^-22}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Dashed, Green}, {Thickness[0.004], 
    Blue}, {Thickness[0.007], Red, DotDashed}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12], 
 GridLines -> {{{0, 
     Blue}, {20*kev^-1, {Blue, Dashed}}, {29*kev^-1, {Blue, Thick, 
      Dashed}}, {40*kev^-1, {Blue, Dashed}}, {80*kev^-1, {Blue, 
      Dashed}}, {60*kev^-1, {Blue, Dashed}}, {100*kev^-1, {Blue, 
      Dashed}}}, {{5*10^-23, {Blue, Dashed}}, {10^-22, {Blue, 
      Dashed}}, {1.5*10^-22, {Blue, Dashed}}}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Automatic}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Energía E [KeV]", FontSize -> 25, Black], 
   Style["f(E)", FontSize -> 25, Black]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \
\(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(bE\), \(\(-1\)/2\)]\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-E\)/\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \
\(B\)] T\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(-\*SuperscriptBox[\(bE\), \
\(\(-1\)/2\)]\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \
\(\(-E\)/\*SubscriptBox[\(k\), \(B\)] T\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(\(-3\) \
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(b\), \(2\)], \(4\\\
\ k\\\ T\)])\), \(1/3\)]\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \
\((\(-\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\((E - \*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \
\(0\)])\), \(2\)], SuperscriptBox[\((\[CapitalDelta]/2)\), \(2\)]]\))\
\)]\)"}, Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[.9]], 
    LabelStyle -> {15}, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}], {0.78, 0.65}],
  FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{6.5 10^-9, 
      8*10^-7.7}, {6.5 10^-9 *kev, kev*8*10^-7.7 }], All}}]
```

I got the following Plot:

[image]

which, in my opinion, is enough to say that the Gaussian function `fgauss[x]` approximates to the product `fexp3[x]` as I was expecting. Here `fexp1[x]` and `fexp2[x]`haven't been reescalated, and that's a difference comparing with Edward Brown's work.

Comment: A few suggestions from looking at your code: 1) Define constants using `Set` (`=`). 2) Define functions such as `fexp1` etc using `SetDelayed` (`:=`). 3) Define your numerical values at arbitrary precision (e.g. `k = 138*10^-18`). 4) Rationalize the argument passed by Plot to your functions, e.g. `Plot[{fexp1[ Rationalize@ x], ... }, ...]`. 5) increase your working precision adding `WorkingPrecision -> 30` as an option to Plot.

Comment: Are you sure about all of the constants?  I know next to nothing about Stellar Astrophysics but `Plot[fexp1[x], {x, 0, 1/1000}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}]` does not have a huge negative exponent issue and the produced curve looks nothing like any of the curves you show.

Comment: `fgauss` has its maximum at $x =\frac{224712\ 23^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\frac{498}{5}} \pi ^{4/3}}{624200000\ 203125\ 17^{2/3}}\approx  4.62393*10^-8$.  That doesn't match with the curves you show.  What have I misinterpreted?

Comment: just rescale your axis it's not that hard to make everything of the order of 1 (like you see on the image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extended comment in an attempt to get a response about the constants presented.

At least one of the constants must be incorrect if the functions should reproduce the posted figure.  Here are two plots with different horizontal and vertical ranges that should the posted figure is not what the current constants and equations can produce:

```
Plot[{fexp1[x], fexp2[x], fexp3[x]}, {x, 6.5 10^-8, 8*10^-8},
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 PlotLegends -> {"fexp1", "fexp2", "fexp3"},
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image: Plot of 3 functions with a particular range]

```
Plot[{fexp1[x], fexp2[x], fexp3[x]}, {x, 6.5 10^-9, 8*10^-8},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2*10^-22}},
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], 
 PlotLegends -> {"fexp1", "fexp2", "fexp3"},
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Plot of 3 functions with another range of values]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response. Actually, plotting fexp3 and fgauss shows exactly the approximation I did. It is working!

Comment: If it's working, it would be helpful if you showed that in your original post.  It certainly looks like you expected your formulas to end up with a figure exactly like the one you posted.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.  Have you sent us on a wild goose chase?

Comment: Sure, I'll post an update as soon as I can. I expected the figure to be, at least, very similar to the one I posted since it's almost the same procedure, only changing some values like the temperature. One caveat is that fexp1 and fexp2 have been reescalated, which in my code is not included and that would be the main difference. The other one is that the horizontal axis is in KeV and this result is in ergs (you can pass from one to another multiplying by the constant kev). More than a wild goose chase, I consider this as a manifestation of my lack of skills plotting in Mathematica. Thanks!!